# Dynamically updating Images to Facebook Page

Tags: html, facebook, dynamic

I want to dynamically update the three images from "*Trend Alert*" in the EDM below: 
http://sophiehart.createsend4.com/t/ViewEmail/r/D3501506593F4120/5AA0D88279FE59B738A555EB6E97B45B

To this Facebook iFrame.
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=198582036826535&sk=app_198582036826535

I'm hoping someone knows a way to update these automagically - I don't want to have to manually change them every week.

The problem as you can see is that the EDM above spits out a different dynamic link every week.

Any one worked on something similar to this before?

This Facebook page currently features the same technique (*The Latest section*) - so if anyone can shed some light on it that would be great!

http://www.facebook.com/rachelzoe

EDIT: I've created the html email template and have got the iframe working - but i'm unsure how to link the images to the Facebook as the link to the html email (campaign monitor) will change weekly?

LINK to EDM: http://sophiehart.createsend4.com/t/ViewEmail/r/D3501506593F4120/5AA0D88279FE59B738A555EB6E97B45B

LINK TO FB: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=198582036826535&sk=app_198582036826535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Facebook Application and install it as a tab in your client's Facebook Page.  This tab will render an iframe with content from any URL that you specify.  This way, you can do anything you want with your webpage (e.g. display 3 dynamic images), and it will be embedded in your client's Facebook Page.

Comment: Thanks JohnnyO - After some delving into the subject shortly after posting this, I got an iFrame working.

The problem now is - i've got this weekly newsletter built in campaign monitor - nothing special just tables and html. Problem is each week the link will change as to where it's uploaded on the campaign monitor servers. 

How can I get the images to link each week without having to edit the Facebook iFrame?

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm a little unclear of what you're trying to do.  If you're like to dynamically update the images, you can do so in your iframe.  Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I'm trying to update images in the iframe on facebook automatically. The images will be put together in an html email template first (then will automagically flow to the iframe on facebook). 
The problem is - that the content is loaded into http://www.campaignmonitor.com/ first, and i'm not sure how to get the links for the images? or send them to facebook?

Comment: Hey Johnny0, have a look at my original post above. I've edited it to include the links to what i'm building so you can get a clearer idea. Let me know if you know a work around! Cheers mate.

Comment: Are you trying to propagate images that are in your campaign emails automatically to the Facebook page?  And every time you send out a new email (e.g. every week), you want the images on your facebook page to update with the images in the newly created email?  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with campaignmonitor, but it looks like they have an API.  Is there anything in the API that you can tap into?

Comment: Hey JohnnyO - Thanks for your help. I contacted Campaign Monitor and there wasn't a way to get around it - as it spits out random server addresses every time you upload content. In the end we scrapped the idea from the Facebook integration. A better way to do it would have been to create a blog and then link the RSS feed into the Facebook iFrame. Now I know for next time ;)